# Combine Worksheets based on certain name structure

Tags: vba, loops, excel, worksheet

Excel file has the following structure of worksheets:

`A1` `A2` `A3` `A4` `B1` `B2` `B3` `C1` `C2` `C3` `C4` `C5` ...

So as you can see 4 times A, 3 times B, 5 times C etc (no even distribution)

What I would like to do:

1) Combine the contents of the worksheets of each type (A, B, C etc.) to newly created summary worksheets, respectively.

So let's say the following is the target structure:
`AX` `A1` `A2` `A3` `A4` `BX` `B1` `B2` `B3` etc.,
whereas `AX` summarizes the content of `A1` to `A4` and `BX` summarizes the content of `B1` to `B3` and so forth.

I have the following routine to combine *all* worksheets to one summary sheet.

```
Sub Combine()    
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).name = "XXX"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2)
Next    
End Sub
```

But now I would like to 'split' this routine up in order to create multiple summary sheets as in the above target structure based on worksheet groups.

2) In the next step I would like to delete all the worksheets except the summary sheets, so that the only thing that remains are the summary worksheets, as in the following illustration:

`AX` `BX` `CX` etc.

As an additional note: I do know how many sheets I have of each type, so for example 4 x A. 3 x B etc, but if possible the program should count the amount of sheets automtically. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here solution based on your requirements

```
Sub combine()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim key, i&
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If Not Dic.exists(UCase(Left(ws.Name, 1))) Then
            Dic.Add UCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)), Nothing
        End If
    Next ws
    For Each key In Dic
    Set wsD = .Sheets.Add(After:= _
                 .Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
      wsD.Name = key & " Summary"
      i = 1
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If UCase(ws.Name) Like key & "*" And _
                ws.Name <> key & " Summary" Then
                ws.Activate: ws.[A1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Resize([A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
                wsD.Activate: Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                i = wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If
        Next ws
    Next key
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "* Summary" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

## Update

Variant without dictionary

```
Sub combine2()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsL As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
Dim i&, cl As Range
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
i = 1
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsL = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    wsL.Name = "List"
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "List" Then
            Set cl = wsL.[A:A].Find(UCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)))
            If cl Is Nothing Then
                wsL.Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(Left(ws.Name, 1))
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    For Each cl In wsL.[A1].CurrentRegion
        Set wsD = .Sheets.Add(After:= _
                     .Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
          wsD.Name = cl.Value & " Summary"
        i = 1
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If UCase(ws.Name) Like cl.Value & "*" And _
                ws.Name <> cl.Value & " Summary" And ws.Name <> "List" Then
                ws.Activate: ws.[A1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Resize([A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
                wsD.Activate: Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                i = wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If
        Next ws
    Next cl
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "* Summary" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Works perfectly. Just an additional question as a beginner: Why do you use dictionary or in other words, could it be solved differently (probably slower..)?

Comment: @EDC yes, your task can be done without using of dictionary. Do you need example how solve it without dictionary?

Comment: It would be interesting for me to learn, but to be fair I don't think it's necessary because your curent solution works fine.

Comment: @EDC variant without using dictionary has been added to my post

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate that very much, thanks a lot for your time and effort :) !